# Best way to return a functions string in another method?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to simplify/cut down a bunch of repeating SQL code in a ruby program, and so am taking repeated lines of code and placing them in their own function.

```
def companies_data
      """
      companies.data->>'creditor_number' as creditor_number,
      companies.data -> 'pay_to_bank_account' ->> 'iban' AS iban,
      company_invoices.from_date,
      company_invoices.to_date,
      concat(company_invoices.r_number, company_invoices.s_number) as rechnungsnummer,
      companies.send_invoice_automatically,
      companies.claim_netting,
      ROUND(company_invoices.total_cents)/100 AS netting_betrag,
      ROUND(company_invoices.billable_dca_fees_recovered_to_creditor_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_fees_recovered_to_creditor_vat_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_flat_fees_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_flat_fees_vat_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_success_fees_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_success_fees_vat_cents + company_invoices.billable_tax_free_dca_costs_cents + company_invoices.billable_taxable_dca_costs_cents + company_invoices.billable_taxable_dca_costs_vat_cents)/100 AS rechnungsbetrag,
      round(company_invoices.billable_dca_fees_recovered_to_creditor_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_fees_recovered_to_creditor_vat_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_flat_fees_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_flat_fees_vat_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_success_fees_cents + company_invoices.billable_dca_success_fees_vat_cents + company_invoices.billable_tax_free_dca_costs_cents + company_invoices.billable_taxable_dca_costs_cents + company_invoices.billable_taxable_dca_costs_vat_cents - company_invoices.total_cents)/100 AS abrechnungsbetrag,
      case_files.currency,
      companies.vat_perspective,
      companies.creditor_payout_by_case_file_invoice
      """
```

I would then like to be able to print that string where I require it inside other functions down the line like

```
def query_for_non_vat_payer

      "SELECT
      distinct NAME,
      #{companies_data}
      FROM case_file_invoices
      JOIN case_files ON case_file_invoices.case_file_id = case_files.id
      JOIN companies ON companies.id = case_files.company_id
      JOIN company_invoices ON company_invoices.id = case_file_invoices.company_invoice_id

      WHERE date_part('year', company_invoices.to_date) = 2021
      AND date_part('month', company_invoices.to_date) = 07
      AND companies.vat_perspective = 'not_vat_payer'
      and companies.invoicing_cycle = 'monthly'"
    end
```

Is    #{companies_data} really the best way?

Comment: nothing wrong with this approach. Decomposing queries is a good way to go. Why aren't you using ActiveRecord query? You can still inject the companies_data in an AR query.

Answer (score 0):

This depends what you call "best". In your case, `companies_data` does not do any calculation, but returns the same string always. In this case, I would find it more natural to not have a function, but a constant:

```
COMPANIES_DATA = ....
```

But I don't know your object model. If you are in a class hierarchy, where `query_for_non_vat_payer` is in a parent class, and the subclasses are allowed/expected to provide their own version of *companies_data*, a method is of course the way to go.